# Let a PDF prompt for an input and insert it

Tags: pdf, input, prompt, interactive

I would like a PDF for some support workers, which should be easily editable.

I need it to ask on first open for a kind of Customer ID. This should be inserted into the document. Is this possible?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires either a smart PDF viewer (such as Adobe Acrobat (Reader) on computers, PDFExpert on iDevices, qPDF on Android) OR serverside support.

In the first case, you would use the `app.response()` method to let the user enter that identifier and then set the result to the according field's value. That could be placed in the PageOpen event of the page the document opens.

Also doing its purpose would be setting the focus to that field when the page opens.

With server support, you could set up a HTML page where the user enters the identifier, submit that to the server, and have the server prefilling the form, using either a ready application like FDFMerge by Appligent, or using one of the PDF creating libraries floating around (such as iText, pdflib, etc.).

Comment: You helped me a lot, thank you so much. One further question: